# PDF LaTeX file on the screen

Tags: pdftex

I work with TeXShop, with a LaTeX source producing a pdf file. I see the pdf file on my screen and I want to use the mouse to  move the pages up and down in that pdf file without using any button. I thought that the Preferences menu of TeXShop would allow me to get this, but I was not able to find how. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the `Preview` tab of`TeXShop->Preferences` set the `Default Page Style` to `Multi-Page` then scrolling with the Mouse should work.

Comment: @Herb Schulz Many thanks for your comment, it works now perfectl.